# Pure JS: Get percentage of the horizontal position clicked within a div?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/UCFtB/33/

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var test = event.clientX / this.offsetWidth * 100;
    alert(test);
});
```

How can I get the percentage of the horizontal position clicked in relation to an elements width in pure Javascript? Right now I get the pixels of the viewport which the rectangle covers divided by the offsetWidth * 100 which gives me something totally different than expected. For example: if I click on the x center of the green box I get 50%.

I read about getBoundingClientRect() but im not sure if this would solve the issue and how it is used.

**Edit:** Could my math be off? As far as im aware, in order to get the percentage I need to calculate N1 / N2 * 100.

Comment: _"How can I get the percentage of the horizontal position clicked within a div in pure Javascript? "_ Horizontal position in relation to width of element ?

Comment: @guest271314 oh yes, I will edit my question.

Comment: `event.clientX` is giving you the x co-ordinate relative to the document.

Comment: @IanJamieson indeed. How can I make it in relation to an elements width?

Comment: @Asperger, I have updated with an answer.

Comment: `event.offsetX / event.target.offsetWidth * 100;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`event.clientX` is giving you the x co-ordinate relative to the document. So you need to take into consideration the `offsetLeft` of the element, as shown below:

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var test = (event.clientX-this.offsetLeft) / this.offsetWidth * 100;
    console.log(test);
});
```

The code above will minus the elements `offsetLeft` from the `clientX` position, this logic will give the x position of the click relative to the element it was clicked in. Your percentage calculation will then work as expected.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ianjamieson/UCFtB/42/

Comment: Ok for the sake of extra information I think I will accept your answer since you added "-this.offsetLeft" and its more complete. The other answer is cleaner though and more correct in this context.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `event.offsetX`

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var test = event.offsetX;
    alert(test);
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UCFtB/38/